# Font Fill Color with Offset Path (Illustrator) Doesn't Work

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

When I write text with script font on Illustrator > create outlines > unite > offset path > group, I cannot select the original text to give it a contrasting fill color. The whole design turns white when I try to make only the text white (without the offset path).

Sometimes I right click after the 'offset path' step and the characters are already grouped.

There is something major/basic I am missing. A solution would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain why you need to outline anything. You can just apply a second fill and then offset that fill via the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

This keeps it as *live* type so it's still easily edited.

It somewhat sounds like you're outlining, dividing, grouping is all a bit unwarranted. But perhaps I'm not fully understanding your goal.

Comment: Thank you so much. No, I think you understand correctly. This looks like what I'm trying to achieve. Much appreciated. I'm following a video tutorial and as a beginner, maybe I'm just not getting certain concepts.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options here:

### Modified approach to your original post:

1. Skip the final group step and use the **Direct Selection Tool**, <kbd>A</kbd>, to select all of the original script type you want to edit:

[image]

[image]

***Note:*** This might be tricky depending on which script font you're using and how easily it can be selected with the Direct Select Tool.

---

### Old School Approach:

1. `Type > Create Outlines` or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to outline the text. Then `Pathfinder > Unite` to create a cohesive shape:

[image]

2. **Copy** <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, **Paste in Front** <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and edit the color of the new shape. **Hide** <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, this shape when finished editing color:

[image]

[image]
*^ Before & After the Hide command <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>*

3. Select the remaining shape and add a stroke (edit color if desired):
   [image]
   ***Note:*** *You can `Object > Expand` this shape but I prefer to keep the stroke intact in the event that I want to edit it again later. However, if you're set on the styling, expand the stroke if you're planning on doing any resizing.*

4. Bring back the front graphic with the **Show All** command, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>:

[image]

5. Repeat **Hide, Edit, Show All** until you get the styling the way you want it.

Comment: No problem! Just remember, there are usually many ways to accomplish things in Illustrator. The more you use it, the more you'll start to lean toward certain approaches that best fit your own workflow. Keep at it!